# How Do I Fix: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException'

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uncaught-exception

I've read that other people have had similar uncaught exceptions, however most seem to be caused by a missing outlet connection. I don't believe mine is related to `IBOutlets` because the `VC` runs fine in most scenarios and so do my other `VCs`.

I think it has to do with `Core Data`. Here's the error, which I believe occurs in my table's `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
2016-01-05 15:18:14.947 Do List[1476:81278] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSManagedObject 0x7fbb89e7cc50> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity TomTask is not key value coding-compliant for the key "completedDate".'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102b5ee65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104cfddeb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102b5eaa9 -[NSException raise] + 9
3   CoreData                            0x0000000102757ec1 -[NSManagedObject valueForUndefinedKey:] + 289
4   Do List                             0x000000010235b9d6 _TFC7Do_List24AllocationViewController9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView21cellForRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 2630
5   Do List                             0x000000010235c24f _TToFC7Do_List24AllocationViewController9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView21cellForRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 79
6   UIKit                               0x0000000103933e43 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 766
7   UIKit                               0x0000000103933f7b -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
8   UIKit                               0x0000000103908a39 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2996
9   UIKit                               0x000000010393d01c -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 92
10  UIKit                               0x0000000103923edc -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 224
11  UIKit                               0x00000001038914a3 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010369659a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010368ae70 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010368acee _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010367f475 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
16  QuartzCore                          0x00000001036acc0a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
17  UIKit                               0x00000001037d4f7c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7329
18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102a8aa31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102a8095c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102a7fe13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102a7f828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
22  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000106bb7ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
23  UIKit                               0x00000001037da610 UIApplicationMain + 171
24  Do List                             0x0000000102368fad main + 109
25  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010a52392d start + 1
26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

**A Few Notes**

There's a particular set of `VCs` that, *if run in a particular order*, cause this error.

The error occurs when I go from `A -> B -> C`, then try to unwind to `A`.

If you look at the exception stack above, the error is happening in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of the `allocViewController`. That `VC` is `B` ,so it shouldn't be loading, just being unwound through.

It references "`CompletedDate`" which is the new thing I added yesterday that kick this whole thing off. `CompletedDate` was an existing `CoreData` attribute which I just started showing in `view controller` `C`.

Comment: The crucial pat of the error message is *the entity TomTask is not key value coding-compliant for the key "completedDate"* –  that means `completedDate` might not be declared as a property with synthesized getter and setter or the property does not exist at all.

Comment: @vadian If you look at the call stack, it refers to "AllocViewController", it looks like it's trying to load its table. However, that's the middle VC that is being unwound through. The viewController table that should be loading up is not AllocViewController. Does that help?

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo: `completedDate` != `CompletedDate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the first line of the error, it looks like you have a class called TomTask which you're trying to use the "completedDate" from, but there isn't a "completedDate" in TomTask.

It appears (from entry #4 in your call stack) you're trying to do this in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method of that view controller.

Comment: Exactly!! Okay, so I'm not crazy. That's what I thought it was saying. Here's the weird thing, no where in the problematic VC do I try to use "CompletedDate". I command-F searched it to double check. So it's acting like I'm calling it, but I'm not. Could it be a Core Data context issue?

Comment: @DaveG try running your code in the debugger with a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions, and it should let you find the line which is triggering that error.

Comment: That pinpointed it and confirmed that the problem is a weird order of operations. The problem seems to stem from VC-A's viewDidLoad getting a new context, THEN VC-B trying to load up its table during the unwind. I'm reading up on unwinds and this behavior is apparently normal, with all the views on the way back loading up before being dismissed?

Comment: I wouldn't have expected intermediate VCs to still be in the view hierarchy; maybe you're not rewinding as far as you think? Or maybe you're using some kind of presentation where VC B is still visible somehow?

Comment: Well A presents B and B presents C. So I'd assume the hierarchy is that A is the parent of B and B the parent of C and the C->A rewind requires going through B? But I didn't expect B to run any code as the unwind ran. But everything I read makes it sound normal to see it visually and to see its code run.